# useEffect hook to filter through the JSON data and spit out new URL params to filter jobs (API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am very close to finishing it but something does not click. I pass the async data from another function to useEffect, filter it through switch + .filter and spit it out to UrlParams to be displayed but it does not filter the jobs that are displayed but only changes the URL (example: http://localhost:3001/jobs=null&location=null&since=null&conditions=remote/hybrid). (also after I change URL params it returns an empty array)

If possible can you please add an explanation for me to understand what I was doing wrong with some examples, would be great to learn that way! I will include all the code components here (useState, useEffect, fetch/filter function +  jsx)

```
//useState
        const [jobCondition, setJobConditionFilter] = useState('On-site/Remote');

//function + useEffect
        const getJobsLocation = useCallback(async (filterCondition) => {
        const jobs = await getJobs();
        const response = jobs.data.nodes;
        const conditionOptions = {
          'On-site': 'in_person',
          Remote: 'remote',
          Hybrid: 'hybrid',
        };
    
        const filteredJobs = await response.filter(
          (job) => job.jobFilter === conditionOptions[filterCondition],
        );
    
        if (!filteredJobs) {
          return {};
        }
        return filteredJobs;
      }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getJobsLocation(jobCondition).then((jobs) => {
      let condition = jobs;
      console.log(condition);
      console.log('this is condition log');
      switch (jobCondition) {
        case 'On-site': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'in_person');
          break;
        case 'Remote': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'remote');
          break;
        case 'Hybrid': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'hybrid');
          break;
        default:
          condition = null;
      }
      if (condition != null) {
        const params = new URLSearchParams({
          jobs: jobFilter || null,
          location: locationFilter || null,
          since: datePosted || null,
          conditions: jobCondition,
        });
        history.push({ pathname: '/', search: `${params.toString()}` });
        console.log(condition);
        console.log('this is condition afterlog');
        return;
      }
      const params = new URLSearchParams({
        jobs: jobFilter || null,
        location: locationFilter || null,
        since: null,
        conditions: null,
      });
      history.push({ pathname: '/', search: `${params.toString()}` });
    });
  }, [jobCondition, getJobsLocation]);


//JSX
      <CustomAutocomplete
        sx={{
          width: '300px',
          marginLeft: '5px',
          marginTop: '10px',
        }}
        placeholder="Location"
        value={jobCondition}
        setValue={setJobConditionFilter}
        options={jobConditionFilter}
        endAdornmentIcon={(
          <div style={{ marginRight: '15px', marginTop: '-10px' }}>
            <ArrowDropDownIcon fontSize="10px" />
          </div>
        )}
      />
```

Comment: can you share more details, as per current snippet I am unable to figure out that are you using two different components or common component for rout with search  params and   without params, 
Things which I noticed is you didn't defined variables for jobFilter, locationfilter, dateposted.

Comment: @PrashantShah  no, they are different components and they don't depend on each other. The vars for jobFilter, locationfilter, dateposted are defined in functions and useStates above in my code but they are irrelevant to this block of code. So I'm using 2 different components here

Comment: Gotcha, I guess something wrong with this function  const filteredJobs = await response.filter(
          (job) => job.jobFilter === conditionOptions[filterCondition],
        );
can u put logs and check above thing may be you are comparing values which are case sensitive and that is the reason you are getting empty array inside filter method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter` creates an immutable array object. It does not mutate the array itself.

If you are trying to filter the condition object, you would have to initialise it again.

```
 case 'On-site': { 
     condition = condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'in_person')
 }
```

Or, If you want to not mutate the condition object, use jobs array to filter as follows:

```
let condition = [];

// Inside switch
case 'On-site': { 
         condition = jobs.filter((job => job.jobLocation === 'in_person')
     }
```

Comment: i tried both ways but neither worked. Still returns an empty array after applying the switch filter..... any ideas? =)